# Creating Settings form using TreeView in C#

Tags: c#, winforms, treeview

I am developing the settings form for the software developed in C#. I was looking at how different software have implemented their settings form.

In most of the cases that I came across, they seem to be using Treeview on the left pane of the form and configuration settings on the right pane.

Ref URL : http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-nMfQoLurxwM/UDXfiZKd4DI/AAAAAAAAAME/IRf6kmxay4w/s1600/bild1.jpg

I was wondering, how the different controls are designed/displayed on the right pane. Do they hide all the controls depending which node is selected in the `TreeView` something like this :

```
   if (treeView1.SelectedNode == treeView1.Nodes[0])
        {
            this.groupBox1.Visible = true;
            this.button1.Visible = true;
            this.textBox1.Visible = true;
            this.textBox2.Visible = true;
            this.label1.Visible = true;
            this.label2.Visible = true;
            this.label3.Visible = true;

        }
        else
        {
            this.groupBox1.Visible  = false;
            this.button1.Visible    = false;
            this.textBox1.Visible   = false;
            this.textBox2.Visible   = false;
            this.label1.Visible     = false;
            this.label2.Visible     = false;
            this.label3.Visible     = false;

        this.groupBox2.Visible  = true;
            this.button2.Visible    = true;
            this.textBox3.Visible   = true;
            this.textBox3.Visible   = true;
            this.labe4.Visible     = true;
            this.label5.Visible     = true;
            this.label6.Visible     = true;

           // bool success = selectColor();
        }
```

Is my understanding correct ? Or do we have a better design approach for creating a settings form.

Thanks

Comment: I am doing something similar and my approach has been to store the settings in an XML file then rebuild the right panel whenever the user clicks on node in the tree. So if xml is a list of items, build a list box. For a string build a text box, etc.

Comment: Add controls in a groupbox. All controls that are present in groupbox hide and visible when groupbox hide and visble.

Answer (score 0):

You can create panels and swap their visibility. So depending on what setting is selected, you fill the controls and display a particular panel.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways but you can have a combination of Treeview control and Tab control. Check this **[link](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6795666/1577396)**. This may help. In this link, the tabpages of tabcontrol are used as treeview control nodes.

Have a look at this [**link**](http://blog.csharphelper.com/2009/12/16/use-a-treeview-to-display-property-pages-or-option-pages-in-c.aspx) too.